# Swift 5 Xcode 10.3 How to set background transparent

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift5, xcode10.3

I want to create a custom `Alert`. So I inserted a content `UIView` with some width and height and the remaining area I want to look dim.

Below ideas I've tried but no luck

**1**- In `Storyboard` I set background custom color black and `opacity` 35%. But After a few second background is turning black.

**2-** Also tried to set background opacity in `UIViewController` by using below code, but not working.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.35)
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if there is enough data to answer it, can you provide more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share what worked for me. I am using `Xcode 10.3` and `Swift 5`

**Step 1-** In `Storyboard` I set `UIView` background custom color black and `opacity 35%`.

**Step 2-** Presented the `ViewController` using the bellow chunk of code.

```
let popupVc : VCAlertMPIN = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCAlertMPIN") as! VCAlertMPIN
popupVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
self.present(popupVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Present your ViewController as `OverCurrentContext` to see parent viewController

```
let popupVc : PopupVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupVC") as! PopupVC
    popupVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    self.presentViewController(popupVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I used your code with some improvement and now it's working fine